# How to save what is inserted into localStorage once the page is refreshed using objects

Tags: javascript, html, json

When I select the value and submit the form the selection is saved the correct user and can be seen in localStorage.

But when I refresh the data which was just saved disappears again.

The key displays [object Object] (it should display the waiter) and the comment is saved but not to the correct user.

Note: This is only fr practice and I only need this to be saved in localStorage

I have tried declaring user as a const as it displays undefined but this did not work.

This is what was returned

`[object Object]  hhh`
`user undefined`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class="pic">
        <form id="mainForm" action="#">
                <section id="form-options">
               <select id="waiters" name="waiterSelection">
                    <!--<option>Waiters</option>-->
                </select>

                <select id="menuMain" name="foodOrder">
                    <!--<option>Mains</option>-->
                </select>

                <input type="text" id="comment" placeholder="Comment">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
            </section>
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src = js/app.js></script>
</html>
```

```
/*

//Waiters Section

*/


//Waiter Constructor
class Waiter {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.order = [];
        this.total = 0;
        this.comment = [];
    }


    //Methods to map() the price argument
    //and then reduce() to get the total  
    addFood(item) {
        this.order.push(item);
        this.total = this.order
            .map(o => o.price, 0)
            .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    };


    //Method to push any comments to the selected waiter
    addComment(c){
        this.comment.push(c) + " ";      
    }


};





//Array to store waiters
const waiters = [
    new Waiter('Timo'),
    new Waiter('Lucian'),
    new Waiter('Arpi')

];






//Adding the waiters to the options menu
const waitersEl = document.getElementById('waiters');
waiters.forEach(({
    name
}) => waitersEl.options.add(new Option(name)));





/*

//Food Section Main

*/

//Food Constructor
class Item {
    constructor(item, price) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
        this.label = `${item} (${price})`;
    }
}



//Main food array
const mainFood = [
    new Item('Peene Primvera', 14),
    new Item("Lasagne", 14),
    new Item("Fillet Steak", 20)
];






//Addin the options for each food and price item inside the dropdown menu
const foodMain = document.getElementById('menuMain');
mainFood.forEach(({
    label,
    item
}, index) => foodMain.options.add(new Option(label, index)));




/*

//Fucntion for when the form is submited it adds the  

*/
const formEl = document.getElementById('mainForm');

formEl.onsubmit = function (e) {

    //Selecting the comment input on the form to pass to the 
    //comment waiters array.
    const comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;


    //Selecting the choosen index from the user food and which waiter orderd //it which waiter.
    //Selects the choosen food to pass to the addFood method in the waiter //class.
    const foodItemIndex = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;
    const foodItem = mainFood[foodItemIndex];


    //Selecting the waiter to push valid informaiton to.
    const waiterName = waitersEl.options[waitersEl.selectedIndex].value;
    const waiter = waiters.find(({name}) => name === waiterName);


    //Logic to check when submited if both feilds are true proceed.
    //The statements check to see which feild values have been entered
    //Then it call's the corresponding method from the waiter class and
    //pushes the value to the choosen array
    if (waiter && comment) {
        waiter.addComment(comment);
        console.log(waiters); 


        //When comment is selected save the comment in localStorage to the correct waiter
        localStorage.setItem(user, comment);
        console.log(user);
    }
    else if (waiter && foodItem){    
        waiter.addFood(foodItem)
        console.log(waiters);
                //When comment is selected save the comment in localStorage to the correct waiter
        localStorage.setItem(user, foodItemIndex);
        console.log(user);
    }
    else if (waiter && foodItem && comment) {
        waiter.addFood(foodItem)
        waiter.addComment(comment);
        console.log(waiters); 
    }

    //waitersEl
    //foodMain
    //comment


    formEl.reset();  




        return false; // prevents redirect/refresh

    };
```

The result should display any user which has added data to it in localStorage even after the page is refreshed.

Ex.

```
{name: "Timo", order: [], total: 0, comment: ["This should be saved after the page is reloaded"]}
comment: ["This should be saved after the page is reloaded"]
name: "Timo"
order: []
total: 0
```

But once I refresh the page this is displayed
user   undefined

Comment: Please appreciate our work and take some time to format the question thoroughly.

Comment: When working on JS/anything frontend, please provide a runnable snippet.

Comment: @sjahan How do I do this, I have seen it done but not sure how?

Comment: @Liam The icon next to 'insert an image', it looks like a paper sheet with <> inside!

Comment: @sjahan But localStorage scripts do not run here due to sandboxing

Comment: @Liam Any console messages?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to store waiter? `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(waiter));` I think you have too many of these `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(waiterName));

    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));`

Comment: @sjahan I was just about to write that about the localStorage not being alowed I tried and it gave me a sandbox error

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(waiter));
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));`  - you need one of them in the beginning and one in the end and you need to know if you want user or waiter

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks I see that I had duplicate code, and have removed the first one. Also var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')); Should be wriiten at the top of the function and at the end do you mean?

Comment: I dont know hot to highlight code in in comments  :(

Comment: Use backticks `\`like this\``

Comment: Yes. Get the user at the beginning of the page and set the select. Then set the user onchange of the select

Comment: I will post the full code now as I am getting errors